# How To Add Pin and Annotation in map in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

How to add Pin and Annotation in Map in ios?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik http://www.cbapcertprep.com/service/index.php?/Download_vehicletrack/DownloadTrackData/35170 in that file i try it but map region will be change automatically

Comment: in ur output contains total 2643 indexes, now what the result u need to show on mapvie

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik using that log,lat put pins on map?

Comment: ya i got it your points, but ur url shows the 2643 values , u need to show the 2643 pin point in ur map

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik only first 20 points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>   

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapvie;   //insert the one map view
```

in .m file

```
NSMutableArray *allocations=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.cbapcertprep.com/service/index.php?/Download_vehicletrack/DownloadTrackData/35170"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSArray *largeArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

NSArray *smallArray = [largeArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 20)]; //this is range for what the result u need



for (int i=0; i<[smallArray count]; i++) {
     CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;

    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    annotationCoord.latitude = [[[smallArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"latitude"]doubleValue ];
    annotationCoord.longitude = [[[smallArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

    annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
    annotationPoint.title = [[smallArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"address"];

    [allocations addObject:annotationPoint];


    MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;

    span.latitudeDelta=THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta=THE_SPAN;

    myRegion.center=annotationCoord;
    myRegion.span=span;

    [self.mapvie setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];

}


[self.mapvie addAnnotations:allocations];
```